# Problema al hacer commit a rama master

Tags: git, git-push, checkout, git-pull

gracias de antemano.
Estoy inciando con git, hay una pequeña aplicación que se montó en un servidor remoto, cada que hago un cambio local lo estoy subiendo con git push, después entró al server por ssh y en la carpeta del proyecto hago git pull (soy el único desarrollando). Todo bien hasta aquí, el problema surgió de que hice git checkout “hash_version_4” en mi local para regresar a una versión anterior de la app, después volví a la ultima versión nuevamente git checkout “hash_version_5” y comencé a trabajar en la ultima versión.

Ahora que hice nuevamente un push con nuevos cambios, me indica lo siguiente: "Already up to date". Y no puedo subir esos cambios a la rama master. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: cuando dices `hash_version_x` quieres decir indicando el ID de una revisión (sin usar una rama)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que cuando indicas `hash_version_x` quieres decir el ID de una revisión eso quiere decir que te *desconectaste* de la rama master (local) así que ella no se movió de la revisión 4 a la revisión 5. Si ese es el caso, y quieres que `master` se ponga en la revision 5:

```
git branch -f master hash_revision_5
git checkout master
```

En este punto podrías hacer el push. La lección más importante a captar en este problema es que git **no trabaja** en base a ramas sino a revisiones. Las ramas no son más que apuntadores a una revisión. Cuando trabajas en una rama (local) y haces un commit, git crea una revisión y *mueve* el apuntador de la rama a esta nueva revisión.... el detalle es que si, como hiciste, le pides a git que haga un checkout de una revisión, git te para en dicha revisión *sin rama* local (lo que se llama **detached HEAD**) y a partir de ese momento al hacer operaciones no hay una rama que apunte a lo que estás haciendo (cosa que es perfectamente posible... y es una de las cosas que más me gusta de git).

Comment: Primero gracias por tu ayuda. Es decir, podría tener n numero de revisiones sin afectar a la rama master y solo en caso de que decida subir una de esas versiones, movería master a dicha revisión?

Comment: Hmm.... pareciera que quieres abrir el tema a _otras_ preguntas no relacionadas específicamente con la anterior. En general lo recomendable es trabajar _con- ramas. Trabajar _sin ramas_ es posible, pero es bastante enrevesado porque los IDs no tienen una relación de secuencia asi que solo por un ID no vas a saber de qué se trata.... aparte, al hacer checkout de revisiones, _pierdes_ los IDs de donde estabas parado anteriormente. Esto no es algo que sea particularmente difícil de resolver. En esos casos se usa `git reflog` pero te estás haciendo la vida mas dificil de forma innecesaria.

Comment: Una vez que ya captas como trabajar con ramas, entonces podrás empezar a jugar con mezclar cosas entre ellas (o hacer cherry-picks.... o rebase, según el caso). Lo importante es saber que las ramas se mueven de forma independiente.... incluso una rama con el mismo nombre que una rama en un repositorio remoto, se mueve de forma independiente a la rama del remoto (aunque tengan el mismo nombre, son ramas independientes)